# How to show native Android views in Flutter applications?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have a native Android App and I want to try Flutter to display all my Android layouts.

I tried the MethodChannel but I feel like I'm missing something.

Can someone explain to me please how can I display a simple view (that exist already in Android xml layout) on Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

Message channels are for passing data and events between Flutter and native app.
What you need is a platform view and [AndroidView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AndroidView-class.html) class in your particular case.

The steps to add the Android view are following:

1. Create Flutter Plugin (you can do this in Android Studio directly)
2. Register your view in the Android app
3. Add your [AndroidView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AndroidView-class.html) your Widget in Flutter app

More information on how to add Flutter to existing app can be found [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps).

Comment: Would it be possible to inflate this native View from an XML layout and then pass it to the PlatformView?

Comment: yes it is possible @droid8421, this might help you https://codingwithtashi.medium.com/flutter-platformview-how-to-host-native-android-and-ios-view-in-flutter-79259faebd91